# How to call each other between Python and C++

Tags: c++, pytorch

PyTorch calls programs written in C++ that cannot be called. The following error is displayed.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'soft_renderer.cuda.load_textures'.
```

Here is the program written in C++：
#include <torch/torch.h>

```
// CUDA forward declarations

at::Tensor load_textures_cuda(`enter code here`
        at::Tensor image,
        at::Tensor faces,
        at::Tensor textures,
        at::Tensor is_update);

// C++ interface

#define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
#define CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x) AT_CHECK(x.is_contiguous(), #x " must be contiguous")
#define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)


at::Tensor load_textures(
        at::Tensor image,
        at::Tensor faces,
        at::Tensor textures,
        at::Tensor is_update) {

    CHECK_INPUT(image);
    CHECK_INPUT(faces);
    CHECK_INPUT(is_update);
    CHECK_INPUT(textures);

    return load_textures_cuda(image, faces, textures, is_update);
                                      
}

//PYBIND11_MODULE(TORCH_EXTENSION_NAME, m) {
PYBIND11_MODULE(load_textures, m) {
    m.def("load_textures", &load_textures, "LOAD_TEXTURES (CUDA)");
}
```